# Firebase flatten structure and create pojo android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have designed this flatten structure in firebase.

```
   {
    "groups": {
        "alpha": {
            "members": {
                "brinchen": true,
                "mchen": true
            },
            "name": "Alpha Tango"
        },
        "bravo": {
            "members": {
                "brinchen": true
            },
            "name": "Bravo Romeo"
        },
        "charlie": {
            "members": {
                "hmadi": true,
                "mchen": true
            },
            "name": "Charlie Whiskey"
        },
        "delta": {
            "name": "Delta Kilo"
        },
        "echo": {
            "name": "Echo Lima"
        },
        "foxtrot": {
            "name": "Foxtrot November"
        }

    },

    "users": {
        "brinchen": {
            "groups": {
                "alpha": true,
                "bravo": true
            },
            "name": "Byambyn Rinchen"
        },
        "hmadi": {
            "groups": {
                "charlie": true
            },
            "name": "Hamadi Madi"
        },
        "mchen": {
            "groups": {
                "alpha": true,
                "charlie": true
            },
            "name": "Mary Chen"
        }

    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1- I want to create pojo class in android for this json. How can i do it?

2- For ex when i update user name like "brinchen -> john" in users json, how can i match jhon to groups json in members in brinchen key ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have **POJO's to deal with the parsing**. For instance, you could/should have the following :

```
// Group or Team, you name it
public class Group {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> members;

    public Group(){}

    public Group(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        this.id = object.getString("id");
        this.name = object.getString("name");
        members = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray list = object.getJSONArray("members");
        if(list!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                members.add(((JSONObject)list.get(i)).getString("name"));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<String> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}


public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> groups;

    public User(){}

    public User(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        this.id = object.getString("id");
        this.name = object.getString("name");
        groups = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray list = object.getJSONArray("groups");
        if(list!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                groups.add(((JSONObject)list.get(i)).getString("groupId"));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<String> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

3) I am not entirely fond of Firebase, **but in normal JSON parsing on Android**, you would do the following :

```
JSONObject teamInformation = Service.getTeamInformation();

ArrayList<Group> myGroup = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray groupList = teamInformation.getJSONObject("groups");
 if(groupList!=null){
    for (int i = 0; i < groupList.length(); i++) {
        myGroup.add( new Group((JSONObject)groupList.get(i)) ); 
    }
}

ArrayList<User> myUsers = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray userList = teamInformation.getJSONObject("users");
 if(userList!=null){
    for (int i = 0; i < userList.length(); i++) {
        myUsers.add( new User((JSONObject)userList.get(i)) ); 
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Based on Firebase documentation, on your **public void onDateChanged(DataSnapShot snap)**
you can convert your result to JSON by doing the following (im not sure of your structure, but its something like this - the Groups JSON part only ):

```
public void onDateChanged(DataSnapShot snap) {
    for (DataSnapshot alert : alerts.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(alert.child("id").getValue();
        System.out.println(alert.child("name").getValue();
        for (DataSnapshot recipient : alert.child("members").getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(recipient.child("name").getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you should read this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. Instead of using Firebase's modified JSON structure, I used basic JSONObjects.
Either way, the mechanism to parse the objects seems to be according to what I specified the onDataChanged(). 
Additionally, by getting those Firebase objects on the method, you can port them into the POJO's like explained.
 Thanks for the heads up!